# Need to copy only values from one range into another without overwriting existing data

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching and toying with no luck. I'm trying to copy the values (not formulas) from one range `n5:n250` to another `m5:m250`, but I don't want to overwrite any existing values in m if they exist. ie, if m5 is blank, I want my sub to copy what's in n5 to m5. If it's already got a value, I want it left alone.

This is what I've been trying with no luck:

```
Sub Reconcile()
     Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To 250
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("M" & i)) Then _
        Range("M" & i) = Range("N" & i)
    Next i
    Worksheets("Master Task List").Range("e5:e58").ClearContents
End Sub
```

The worksheets line is the second function I'd like the sub to accomplish when I hit the appropriate button.

I would very much appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: what is it doing that is in error, or on which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: On my phone at the moment so can't try it in code. You could find the blank cells in column M using special cells. Offset that range to column N and copy/paste back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your rows in column `M`, and if the value is equal to `vbNullString`, set the value to the one in column `N`.

```
Sub Reconcile()

    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For i = 5 To 250

            If .Cells(i, "M") = vbNullString Then
                .Cells(i, "M") = .Cells(i, "N")
            End If

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

This is the routine using `IsEmpty`. Your example you were using `Not IsEmpty`. When `IsEmpty = True`, that means that it's empty. With you placing `Not` in front you are saying **Is Not Empty**.

```
Sub Reconcile()

    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For i = 5 To 250

            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "M")) Then
                .Cells(i, "M") = .Cells(i, "N")
            End If

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Keep in mind, `Worksheets(1)` is for illustrative purposes. You may need to change this for your specific worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could pick out the blank cells and just move those across in a loop.
I've added an `On Error Resume Next` around setting the range as I don't know of any other way to trap the error that occurs if there are no blank cells.

```
Sub Reconcile()

    Dim rBlanks As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rBlanks = .Range("M5:M250").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rBlanks Is Nothing Then
            For Each rCell In rBlanks
                rCell = .Cells(rCell.Row, "N") 'Could also use 14 or rcell.Offset(,1) in place of "N"
            Next rCell
        Else
            MsgBox "No blanks found."
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```